# Applying formatting to a SpreadsheetDocument using OpenXML SDK 2.5 doesn't work

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, openxml-sdk

I'm using OpenXML SDK 2.5 to create an Excel file - aka SpreadsheetDocument in OpenXML lingo - and then apply some sort of formatting to the cells.

When opening the generated file in Excel this formatting didn't work at all, despite the generated file passing validators, both the one I used in my code and the OpenXML SDK 2.5 Productivity Tool validator.

I even went through and manually copied and pasted snippets of XML from a working version - created by saving a copy of my generated file in Excel - to my generated file but that mostly only resulted in invalid files.

Everything in the generated XML looked as it should, with correct references from the worksheet XML data to the stylesheet XML data, and correctly formatted XML to define the style (in this case simply changing the cell content to **bold**).

After hours of troubleshooting and chatting with the best and brightest AI bots (Chat GPT 4) I finally figured out the issue.

See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually two things that might trip you up, and especially if you only rely on AI advice.

The OpenXML standard requires at least one *Fonts*, *Borders*, and *Fills* object in a *Stylesheet* for it to be valid, and omitting any one of these will result in a file that Excel can't open. I found that this is something that the AI at times didn't care to explain and it wasn't obvious when reading the documentation (at least not to me).

However, the thing that caused my problem, that I couldn't find any information about in the documentation, and that the AI never mentioned - and still passed validation as mentioned above, is that I needed a default *CellFormat* object in my stylesheet, even if I never reference it.

I can't share all of my code since it does a lot when adding formatting but this is the gist of it.

```
// Create a CellFormats collection if it doesn't exist
stylesheet.CellFormats ??= new CellFormats();
stylesheet.CellFormats.Count ??= 0;

// Create a default CellFormat that we're not using but is required for the rest of the formatting to work
CellFormat defaultCellFormat = new CellFormat();
stylesheet.CellFormats.Append(defaultCellFormat);

// Create a new CellFormat that we actually use
var cellFormat = new CellFormat();

// Add all the formatting to the CellFormat
// Your code here...

// Append the new CellFormat object to the CellFormats collection and get its index
stylesheet.CellFormats.Append(cellFormat);
stylesheet.CellFormats.Count = (uint)stylesheet.CellFormats.ChildElements.Count;
uint formatIndex = (uint)stylesheet.CellFormats.ToList().IndexOf(cellFormat);

// Apply the formatting to the current cell by setting its StyleIndex property
cell.StyleIndex = formatIndex;
```

This might be unique to my code, but hopefully this saves someone else the trouble of wading through pages and pages of OpenXML documentation. :)